# SASS styles apply when saving scss file but not on browser refresh

Tags: html, css, media-queries, sass

I am using major media breakpoints in the head of the doc:

```
<!-- Base = Normalize for basic and small screens -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
<!-- Enhanced = Styles for devices that understand media queries -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/enhanced.css" media=”screen, handheld” />
<!-- Medium = Devices larger then generlized phone size -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/medium.css" media=”only screen and (min-width:37em)”/>
<!-- Large = Larger tablets and desktops -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/large.css" media=”only screen and (min-width:45em)”/>
<!-- Extralarge = Large displays and tv -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/extralarge.css" media=”only screen and (min-width:60em)”/>
```

The four stylesheets are made up of several _partials. When I save in one of the scss files codekit runs and Chrome refreshes and everything renders just fine. However when I refresh the browser all the styles are not applied. The css files are present but nothing gets applied. Everything worked fine when I had one screen.scss file with media queries inside that file but now that they are split up nothing applies. What am I missing here?

Comment: This is a local development site. I am using compass as well.

Comment: If I @import all of the stylesheet.scss files into screen.scss (instead of the _partials into the stylesheets) the styles apply on browser refresh.

Comment: I removed minor breakpoints within each partial file, no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see curly fancy quotes in your HTML. Fixing them should cause your media queries to be recognized:

```
<!-- Base = Normalize for basic and small screens -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
<!-- Enhanced = Styles for devices that understand media queries -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/enhanced.css" media="screen, handheld" />
<!-- Medium = Devices larger then generlized phone size -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/medium.css" media="only screen and (min-width:37em)"/>
<!-- Large = Larger tablets and desktops -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/large.css" media="only screen and (min-width:45em)"/>
<!-- Extralarge = Large displays and tv -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/extralarge.css" media="only screen and (min-width:60em)"/>
```

Comment: Yep. That fixed it. That is what you get when you don't pay attention to the code highlighting. Thanks-

Comment: I don't blame you - there wasn't any highlighting to begin with. I added some tags to the question that allowed it to be highlighted, so it was hard to spot at first.